# JSON reply with PHP in loop from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

Trying to communicate with some external API but only thing I got is example reply:

```
 {"SUCCESS":[{"Hello msg":"Successfull list","LIST":{"Group 1":{"GROUPNAME":"Group 1","Persons":{"1":{"ID":2588,"NAME":"John Doe"}}}}}],"apiversion":"0.1"}
```

When I echo it, it's ok, but this array is little confusing for me, especially how to not get [] where I get array from mysql and get them between "SUCCESS" and "Hello msg"

This is best what I got so far:

```
$someArray=array();
$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from tbl_Persons");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($someArray,[
                'ID'=>$row['id'],
                'NAME'=>$row['name']
]);}


$response=array();
$response['SUCCESS']=array();
$resposne['SUCCESS']=array('Hello msg'=>'Successfull list');
$response['SUCCESS']['List']['Group 1']=array('GROUPNAME'=>'Group 1');
$response['SUCCESS']['List']['Group 1']['Persons']=$someArray;
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: I think `persons` or in other words `$someArray` is associative, but not numeric in the json example. try `$someArray[(string)$i] = array("ID" = > ....`

Comment: which tag data you want to pick from there ?

Comment: @RoyalBg Gives me:  PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type

Comment: @Abhishek I want to make same response, but when getting ID and NAME in loop from MySQL I'm unable to replicate JSON structure especially I get [] in the middle of response or every group ID+NAME

Answer (score 0):

Create a counter variable and use it as a string key in your array:

```
$someArray=array();
$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from tbl_Persons");
$i=1;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $someArray[(string)$i++]=['ID'=>$row['id'],'NAME'=>$row['name']];
}
```